# capturar los valores de una tabla con contenido editable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una tabla editable donde no obligatoriamente se deben llenar todos los datos, pero al momento de realizar el guardado, el cual no me genera ningún error al momento de guardarlo, solo llego a ver el id de la lista desplegable del dropdownlist, pero los demas datos no se muestran ...
Estuve leyendo en otros foros y dicen que tengo que capturar el valor pero no eencontrado mayor ejemplo o detalle de eso

```js
function guardaConsulta() {
            let t1 = document.getElementById("medicamento1").value;
            let t2 = document.getElementById("concentracion1").value;
            let t3 = document.getElementById("idpresentacion1").value;
            let t4 = document.getElementById("cant1").value;
            let t5 = document.getElementById("medicamento2").value;
            let t6 = document.getElementById("concentracion2").value;
            let t7 = document.getElementById("idpresentacion2").value;
            let t8 = document.getElementById("cant2").value;                
                      
            var idEntidad = document.getElementById("idEntidad").value;
            var motivo = document.getElementById("motivo").value;
            var diagnostico = document.getElementById("diagnostico").value;
            let tratamiento = [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8];
            var fechaFin = document.getElementById("txfinTratamiento").value;
            var foto = document.getElementById("imgFoto").src;
            var frm = new FormData();
            frm.append("idEntidad", idEntidad);
            frm.append("motivo", motivo);
            frm.append("diagnostico", diagnostico);
            frm.append("tratamiento", tratamiento);
            frm.append("finTratamiento", fechaFin);
            frm.append("imagen", foto);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Consulta/Guardar",
                data: frm,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "ok") {
                        correcto("Se guardo correctamente");
                        document.getElementById("btnCerrado").click();
                    } else {
                        error("Ocurrio un error");
                        document.getElementById("divError").innerHTML = data;
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

```html
<table class="table table-sm text-center" id="tablaeditable">
                    <thead class="table-info">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center">Medicamento o Insumo</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Concentracion</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Forma Farmaceutica</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Cant</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td contenteditable="true" id="medicamento1"></td>
                            <td contenteditable="true" id="concentracion1"></td>
                            <td>@Html.DropDownList("idpresentacion1", listaPre, new { @class = "form-control form-control-chosen", @style = "width:200px" })</td>
                            <td contenteditable="true" id="cant1"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td contenteditable="true" id="medicamento2"></td>
                            <td contenteditable="true" id="concentracion2"></td>
                            <td>@Html.DropDownList("idpresentacion2", listaPre, new { @class = "form-control form-control-chosen", @style = "width:200px" })</td>
                            <td contenteditable="true" id="cant2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el valor seleccionado en un elemento select (DropDownList en tu código), puedes usar la propiedad selectedIndex para obtener el índice del elemento seleccionado y, a partir de eso, acceder a la propiedad value del elemento correspondiente en la lista de opciones del select.

Por ejemplo, si quieres obtener el valor seleccionado en un select con el id idpresentacion1, puedes hacer algo así:

```
let select = document.getElementById("idpresentacion1");
let selectedIndex = select.selectedIndex;
let selectedOption = select.options[selectedIndex];
let selectedValue = selectedOption.value;
```

Luego, puedes usar la variable selectedValue para guardar el valor seleccionado en el select en el objeto FormData que envías a la página de destino mediante el método $.ajax (en lugar de usar select.value, que no te dará el resultado esperado ya que solo te devolverá el valor del primer elemento de la lista de opciones del select).

También puedes obtener el texto de la opción seleccionada accediendo a la propiedad text del elemento option correspondiente en lugar de usar la propiedad value. Por ejemplo:

```
let selectedText = selectedOption.text;
```

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: gracias x tu respuesta, pude obtener el valor de la lista asi :  let pre1 = document.getElementById("idpresentacion1");   let t3 = pre1.options[pre1.selectedIndex].text; Pero aun me falta de las otras celdas